# PropertyNotFoundException exporting datatable with column getting text from backingbean method

Tags: primefaces

I have an primefaces datatable and column values also got displayed by using following code.

```
<c:forEach items="#{consolidatedReportByEquipmentBean.chairAmcDescList}"                            var="amcDescObj">
  <c:forEach items="#{consolidatedReportByEquipmentBean.chairPartsList}"
                                                            var="partsObj">
        <p:column style="text-align:center">
              <p:outputLabel value="#{consolidatedReportByEquipmentBean.parseTotalNoOfPartsChanged(chairPartsRepairedObj.chairServiceAutoId,amcDescObj.amcDescAutoId,partsObj.chairPartsAutoId)}"></p:outputLabel>
        </p:column>
</c:forEach>
```

By when i click datatable exporter,it results in following error.

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:
/Admin/Reports/Consolidate/EquipmentServicedRecord.xhtml @279,184 value="#{consolidatedReportByEquipmentBean.parseTotalNoOfPartsChanged(chairPartsRepairedObj.chairServiceAutoId,amcDescObj.amcDescAutoId,partsObj.chairPartsAutoId)}": 
Property 'parseTotalNoOfPartsChanged' not found on type com.amcservicing.bean.ConsolidatedReportByEquipmentBean
```

Comment: The error message is clear. There is an error in class  `consolidatedReportByEquipmentBean`at method `parseTotalNoOfPartsChanged()`. It seems a null value is returned back.

Comment: @reporter: value is displayed in columns with out any error. Error says property not found. But when i click "Print" then there is no issues. When i click pdf or xlsx exporter then i got the error.

Comment: Are you sure that an object for Excel or PDF export has being created? Have you debuged your code?

Comment: can you post the xhtml code for exporter and any preprocessor and postProcessor code too

Comment: Read the exception carefully, what for the outputLabel in the xhtml to is a **method expression** when it is displayed, is clearly interpreted as a **value expression** when the data is exported. This is either an omission in the PrimeFaces exporter or it is in the mean time already fixed and you are using an old version (hence to **always** post as much detailed version info as possible)

Comment: Actually the data is displayed fine and only problem while exporting. the exporter for datatable with method expression inside column is working fine with primefaces exporter but there is no headers inside columngroup. But with primefaces extension only i am facing problem with method expression. Why i am using method expression is because of dynamic columns.